# What is the AudioIPC Server?

Tags: sound, settings, output

In the `Settings-Sound` there is sometimes an entry in the `Output` section called `AudioIPC Server` (Ubuntu 19.04). A quick internet search did not reveal much information.
What is the AudioIPC Server?
When does it show up in the Sound Settings?
Is it installed by default? Or with a certain program?
By which program or service is it used?
Anything else that might be interesting?

Comment: 4th link (your q is 3rd) when searching for "AudioIPC server" https://brokkr.net/2018/05/24/down-the-drain-the-elusive-default-pulseaudio-sink/  :) It is the fallback for pulseaudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind) for the hint. AudioIPC Server is a **[fallback device for pulseaudio](https://brokkr.net/2018/05/24/down-the-drain-the-elusive-default-pulseaudio-sink/)**, which is used “[if the stream has not been seen before](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/DefaultDevice/)”.
The [PulseAudio-Documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/DefaultDevice/) reveals more details:
*"As far as Pulseaudio devices are concerned "default" and "fallback" are synonyms. "fallback" is the more accurate description. For legacy reasons the command line utilities use the term "default".

Whenever a new stream appears, PulseAudio's stream-restore module checks if the same stream has been seen before, and if it is, then the stream is connected to the same sink or source that was used previously. There is a concept of a "fallback" device, which is used if the stream has not been seen before."*

In my case especially **Firefox**' audio output appears as `AudioIPC Server: AudioStream`:
[image]
Bug reports are filed: [Media and application name is not descriptive](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1435614) and [Wrong Audio Stream Name in Ubuntu 18.04 Volume Mixer](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1488666#c4).
[And apparently there has been work towards a fix](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1488666#c4) and it was [released on the 24th July 2019](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1488666#a27838908_274575).